# Creating a map/contents of any object

Tags: python, list, recursion, python-3.6

In Python 3.6. What I'm trying to do is create a function that can accept any object and then generate a tree like contents.

Similar to a book:

```
1. Object
 1.1 member: integer
 1.2 member: list
   2.1 list: element 1
   2.2 list: element 2
 1.3 member: string
```

My purpose is to use the numbers as a key for a technical readout, the number could also stand in for a more understandable ID number than id() generates. Because the objects I want to deal with are all types, I'd like the function to be recursive. Here is what I have so far:

```
def contents(a, n = 0, lim = 5, prefix=""):
    index = 1
    text = ""
    j = None
    if n < lim:
        try:
            for i in a.__dict__:
                text = text + "\n" + ("\t" *(n)) + prefix + str(index) + ", " + str(i) + ": " + contents(a.__dict__[i], n = n + 1, prefix=str(n)+".") + ""
                index += 1
        except:
            try:
                for i, j in a.items():
                    text = text + "\n" + ("\t"*(n)) + prefix + str(index) + ", " + str(i) + ": " + contents(i, n = n + 1, prefix=str(n)+".") + ""
                    index += 1
                except:
                    if isinstance(a, str):
                        text = text + "\n" + ("\t"*(n)) + prefix  + str(index) + ", " + str(a) + " "
                    else:
                        try:
                            for i in a:
                                text = text + "\n" + ("\t"*(n)) + prefix  + str(index) + ", " + str(i) + contents(i, n = n + 1, prefix=str(n)+".") + " "
                                index += 1

                    except:
                        text = text + "\n" + ("\t"*(n)) + prefix  + str(index) + ", " + str(a) + " "

    else:
        text = text + "limit. \n"
    return text
```

a is the object, n is the current number of recursion, lim is the recursion limit, prefix has to do with the object ID displayed.

Here's the testing object

```
class Aclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [12, 24]
        self.b = 5

a = [Aclass(), 1, "2", 3, 4, Aclass(), {"c":"d","e":"f"}]
```

The problem I'm running into has to do with strange revursive behavior with lists, I already made an exception for strings, because the string would register as an iterable made up of iterables, which would recurse indefinitely if I hadn't put in a limit. Now simple lists of numbers like [1, 2, 3, 4] will often list the number twice as if it breaks down into a one item list [1] and then reports on the number inside: 1.

Comment: [`reprlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html) and especially its [`@recursive_repr` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr) exist to solve problems with self-recursive data structures.

Comment: Although that doesn't exactly solve my problem, because I'm dealing with builtin data types that can't be simply overloaded. However the `reprlib.Repr` object might be a useful example to follow, for instance I can overload the `repr_instance` method and almost get the functionality I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint) module, which is part of the standard distribution. It solves this problem already, and so might serve as a basis for your code. (I can easily see, for instance, adding numbers by subclassing the `PrettyPrinter` class.)

This code:

```
class Aclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [12, 24]
        self.b = 5

a = [Aclass(), 1, "2", 3, 4, Aclass(), {"c":"d","e":"f"}]

import pprint
s = pprint.pformat(a, indent=4)
print(s)
```

Produces this output:

```
[   <__main__.Aclass object at 0x1060fb160>,
    1,
    '2',
    3,
    4,
    <__main__.Aclass object at 0x1060fb198>,
    {'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have to take a closer look at the pprint module.